# fontawesome icons do not work properly with kableextra styling

Tags: quarto, kable, kableextra

kable output is inconsistent or do not work properly with font awesome icons in a quarto document. Below is quarto code and output screenshots.

### kable

````
---
title: FontAwesome and Kable
---

{{< fa brands pagelines >}} {{< fa seedling >}} {{< fa plant-wilt >}}  

```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)

icons <- c("{{< fa brands pagelines >}}","{{< fa seedling >}}","{{< fa plant-wilt >}}")

x <- iris %>%
  slice(c(1,51,101)) %>%
  mutate(Species=paste0("<span style='background-color:#d7bde2;padding:1px 3px;border-radius:3px;'>",icons," ",Species,"</span>"))
```

```{r}
kable(x)
```

```{r}
kable(x,format="html",escape=FALSE)
```
````

[image: Screenshot 2023-09-08 at 13 26 34]

### kableExtra

````
---
title: FontAwesome and KableExtra
---

{{< fa brands pagelines >}} {{< fa seedling >}} {{< fa plant-wilt >}}  

```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

icons <- c("{{< fa brands pagelines >}}","{{< fa seedling >}}","{{< fa plant-wilt >}}")

x <- iris %>%
  slice(c(1,51,101)) %>%
  mutate(Species=paste0("<span style='background-color:#d7bde2;padding:1px 3px;border-radius:3px;'>",icons," ",Species,"</span>"))
```

```{r}
kable(x)
```

```{r}
kable(x,format="html",escape=FALSE)
```
````

[image: Screenshot 2023-09-08 at 13 26 59]

### kableExtra with styling

````
---
title: FontAwesome and KableExtra
description: Using FontAwesome icons with kableExtra HTML table
execute:
  message: false
  warning: false
---

{{< fa brands pagelines >}} {{< fa seedling >}} {{< fa plant-wilt >}}  

```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

icons <- c("{{< fa brands pagelines >}}","{{< fa seedling >}}","{{< fa plant-wilt >}}")

x <- iris %>%
  slice(c(1,51,101)) %>%
  mutate(Species=paste0("<span style='background-color:#d7bde2;padding:1px 3px;border-radius:3px;'>",icons," ",Species,"</span>"))
```

```{r}
kable(x)
```

```{r}
kable(x,format="html",escape=FALSE)
```

```{r}
kable(x,format="html",escape=FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options=c("hover","condensed","responsive"), position="center", full_width=FALSE)
```
````

[image: Screenshot 2023-09-08 at 13 27 29]

```
knitr 1.43
kableExtra 1.3.4
quarto 1.3.433
```